# Moving Wordpress site subdirectory errors

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, testing, migration, subdirectory

I have just moved my testing development subdirectory worpdress installation to my root folder using the WP-Clone plugin.

The problem now is my main site (previously mysite.com ) shows (mysite.com/site) now. and the subdirectory is shwoing in all my links

I have tried going to settings and removed the /site from wordpress URL and Site address URL.
But it broke my site and disabled me from accessing my wp-login.php .
I fixed it by editing my wp-config.php and adding :

```
define('WP_HOME','https://mysite.com/site');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://mysite.com/site');
```

and now my website works perfectly. But it still shows mysite.com/site and i am unable to edit my URL and Siteaddress from my wp dashboard anymore.

How do I Remove my website subdirectory (/site) and still have it work and not break my site's themes and all? How do I go about this? Really really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Okay I have removed the 2 lines in the wp-login.php.
And now I am able to access my site through wp-login.php
Now my site URL shows : mysite.com/site
Site Address URL : mysite.com/site

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding those constants to wp-config.php you're overruling any setting in the database. That's why you can't edit them in the admin panel.

So the first step is to change those constants to:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://domain.com');
```

Then delete your htaccess file. (.htaccess in your root folder).

Once you've done this navigate to http://domain.com/wp-login.php

Login to your site and go to Settings -> Permalinks. Hit save which will regenerate your htaccess file.

Finally you'll need to update existing links. I'd suggest installing a plugin called 'Velvet Blues Update URLs'.

Comment: I have done as instructed and changed the URLs and deleted the .htaccess file. Now i Try logging in to http://domain.com/wp-login.php . But after i enter details, it redirects to site.com/site and I cant login. What do I do now?

Comment: And My themes and pages all broke!

Comment: Okay now I have removed the 2 lines of code in wp-config.php. And can edit the URL and site URL in the settings in wp dashboard. both of them show mysite.com/site. What do I do here?